# Is the length of linear combination of a convergent sequence of a Banach subspace bounded?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $W$ be a separable Banach space over the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$

Let $B \subset W$ be a subset of $W$ such that $B$ is linearly independent, compact and connected.

Let $U=\operatorname{span}(B)$

Let $\{v_m\}_{m \in \mathbb{N}} \in U$ be a sequence of elements in $U$, so 
$$
v_m=\sum_{j=1}^{Lv_m} a_{m,j}b_{m,j}
$$
where $a_{m,j} \in \mathbb{C}$, $b_{m,j} \in B$ and $Lv_m$ is the number of linearly independent vectors whose linear combination is $v_m$, so $Lv_m$ is a finite integer.

Let $b_0 \in B$ such that
$$
\lim_{m \to \infty} v_m = b_0
$$
My question is if $Lv_m$ is bounded, that is if
$$
\sup_{m \in \mathbb{N}} Lv_m < \infty
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Let $v_m$ be any sequence as above. If $Lv_m$ stays bounded, pick $m$ elements $c_{n,j}\in B$ that are not involved in $v_m$. Define
$$
w_m = v_m + \frac{m^{-1}}{\sum_{j=1}^m \|c_{n,j}\|} \sum_{j=1}^m c_{n,j}
$$
By construction, $Lw_m \ge m$. Also, $\|w_m-v_m\|\le 1/m$, so $w_n\to b_0$ still holds.

Comment: thanks for your answer @Gerry